# How to get http host in ZF 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, http-host

How can I get the host address?
For example, my site is located here: *http://example.org/index/news/*
and I want to extract only *http://example.org/*.

I ask about ZF function. I know about $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] but I'm looking for something native.

Answer (score 5):

From a controller:

```
$this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_HOST')
```

that'll give you `example.org`, the rest you'll have to add around it.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is perfectly fine, but a few things you might want to keep in mind.

```
$this->getRequest();
```

is a function/method call, which means overhead that isn't necessairy, since controllers have a protected `$_request` property, so

```
$this->_request
```

the `getRequest` method is does little more than exposing the `$_request` property (it's a public method):

```
public function getRequest()
{
    return $this->_request;
}
```

should be slightly more performant. Also, if you look a the source for the `getServer` method:

```
public function getServer($key = null, $default = null)
{
    if (null === $key) {
        return $_SERVER;
    }

    return (isset($_SERVER[$key])) ? $_SERVER[$key] : $default;
}
```

There really is no point in using the method without supplying a default value, other than syntactic sugar. 
The quickest way will always be

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

However, combining the best of both worlds, the safest (and most ZF-like way) would be:

```
$this->_request->getServer('HTTP_HOST', 'localhost');//default to localhost, or whatever you prefer.
```

The full code you're looking for might be:

```
$base = 'http';
if ($this->_request->getServer('HTTPS', 'off') !== 'off')
{
    $base .= 's';
}
$base .= '://'.$this->_request->getServer('SERVER_NAME', 'localhost').'/';
```

Which, in your case, should result in `http://expample.org/`.
[see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for a full list of SERVER params you can get, what they mean and what the values might be...